# Quoted onclick function? How to correctly markup it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this sharing window but i don't know how to correctly write it!

I want to do something like this whith: **"link","title",200,200**

```
var sharelink = "'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Promozione&p[url]=http://www.mysexyurl.com&p[summary]=mysexysummaryhere&p[images][0]=http://contat.eu/facebook/vtour/"+modello[i][1]+"','Condividi%20su%20Facebook','600','600'";

<div onclick="popup("link","title",200,200)"
```

For more info see 
    http://jsfiddle.net/Z9AUH/1/

Real demo http://contat.eu/facebook/vtour/

Comment: do you wanna add like this    <div onclick="popup("+link+")" ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem happends becouse of duble quote in link var ...

Comment: <div onclick="popup("+link.replace(/"/g, '\\"')+")"

Comment: can you send your proper code  { <div onclick="popup("link","title",200,200)" } ?

Comment: i wanna know how you created this code { <div onclick="popuper("a","b",222,222)">WHY IT DOESNT WORK!!</div> }

Comment: http://contat.eu/facebook/vtour/

Comment: can you send only that line if you still cannot find a solution

Comment: UP! Please, still not solved. Strange problem..

Comment: its easy to solve if you send us the line { <div onclick="popuper("a","b",222,222)">WHY IT DOESNT WORK!!</div> } . the actual line

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dah8b/

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is solution

```
<script>
    var popuper = function (pageURL, title, w, h) {
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (+w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (+h / 2);
    var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
}
</script>

<div onclick="popuper('a','b','222','222')">WHY IT DOESNT WORK!!</div>
```

On fiddle just put everything to html window

Comment: how about the var ?? i cant remove dubble quotes...? It's become: var link = "'link','title',200,200"

Comment: Hi thanks, it's work when used in console but doesnt work when called with onclick event...can you help me another bit? The code is implemented on this page:http://contat.eu/facebook/vtour/  but stil not work